# Почему блоки не выравниваются горизонтально?

Tags: html, css

Есть 3 блока. Они в другом одном блоке. Но они не выравниваются горизонтально ровно. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<div>
    <div class="l"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="r"></div>
</div>

.l {margin: 0 auto; float: left; width:33%; height:50px; background: red;}
.c {margin: 0 auto; width:33%; height:50px; background: green;}
.r {margin: 0 auto; float: right; width:33%; height:50px; background: yellow;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Блок 'r',  идёт за необтикающим блоком 'c' и начинает его с новой строки, можно его поставить до блока 'с', тогда будет, как надо:

http://jsfiddle.net/bfwefwcu/

Ещё можно сделать центральный блок инлайновым (display: inline-block), но тогда его центрировать придется, ставя родительскому элементу значение text-align: center

http://jsfiddle.net/o4p4f3ey/1/

Answer (score 0):

Дайте блоку родителя `text-align: center;`, а дочерним `display: inline-block;`вместо `float` везде.